# Text.remove for phone number formatting in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, substring, string-formatting, phone-number

I have a textbox for a phone number that formats the phone number to look like this:

(123) 456-7891

but I want it to change back to just numbers when the user is finished with the data entry:

1234567891

Here's my code for formatting the number:

```
        Dim newNumber As String
    If txtContactNumberNew.Text.Length = 0 Then
        txtContactNumberNew.Text = "N/A"
    ElseIf txtContactNumberNew.Text.Length = 10 Then
        newNumber = "(" & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(0, 3) & ") " & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(3, 3) & "-" & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(6, 4)
        txtContactNumberNew.Text = newNumber
    ElseIf txtContactNumberNew.Text.Length > 10 Then
        newNumber = "(" & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(0, 3) & ") " & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(3, 3) & "-" & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(6, 4) & " x " & txtContactNumberNew.Text.Substring(10)
        txtContactNumberNew.Text = newNumber
    ElseIf txtContactNumberNew.Text.Length < 10 Then
        MsgBox("Not enough Numbers! Please retype the Phone number", vbExclamation, "Not enough Numbers")
        Return
    End If
```

Since I added the parenthesis would this change my character count? I just want the formatting removed when the form is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the trim method to remove unwanted characters. You could then get the character count of the result.

```
 'List of characters to remove
  Dim charsToTrim() As Char = { "("c, ")"c, "-"c}
  Dim result As String = txtContactNumberNew.Text.Trim(charsToTrim)
```

taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the () removed can't you just use replace from regex

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str,"[\(|\)|\-|\s]","")
```